# Consolidate Data From Multiple Worksheets And Workbooks With Different Column Headers Into 1 Sheet Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to consolidate data from multiple worksheets and Workbooks with different column headers into single worksheet name (Database) using vba. Currently I have the below code that opens two workbooks and copies  the sheets to the destination workbook. Then currently (Database sheet) in the destination workbook has fixed headers which are then matched with headers in all the copied sheets and then copies all the row data and pastes into Database sheet for the respective column header.

```vb
Sub CopySheetFromClosedWB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim closedBook1 As Workbook
Dim closedBook2 As Workbook

    Set closedBook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\New folder\Exec_072021.xlsb", Password:="**********")
    Set closedBook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\New folder\Non Exec_072021.xlsb", Password:="**********")
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    For Each ws1 In closedBook1.Sheets
        ws1.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
        ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "_Exec"
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Next ws1
    closedBook1.Close SaveChanges:=False
     
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    For Each ws2 In closedBook2.Sheets
         ws2.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
         ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Name & "_NonExec"
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
    Next ws2
    closedBook2.Close SaveChanges:=False
     
    Call UpDateData
    MsgBox "Database Created!!"

        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

```vb
Sub UpDateData()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long, wData As Worksheet, _
    Process(1 To 10) As String, iProc As Long, Dict As Object
    Process(1) = "Manila_Exec"
    Process(2) = "Cebu_Exec"
    Process(3) = "Davao_Exec"
    Process(4) = "CDO_Exec"
    Process(5) = "Bacolod_Exec"
    Process(6) = "Manila_NonExec"
    Process(7) = "Cebu_NonExec"
    Process(8) = "Davao_NonExec"
    Process(9) = "CDO_NonExec"
    Process(10) = "Bacolod_NonExec"
    Set wData = Sheets("Database")
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With wData
    .UsedRange.Offset(1).Clear
    For j = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Len(.Cells(1, j)) > 0 Then Dict.Add LCase$(.Cells(1, j)), j
    Next j
    End With
    i = 2
    For iProc = 1 To 10
    With Sheets(Process(iProc))
    n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If Dict.exists(LCase$(.Cells(1, j))) Then
    k = Dict(LCase$(.Cells(1, j)))
    .Cells(2, j).Resize(n - 1).Copy wData.Cells(i, k).Resize(n - 1)
    End If
    Next j
    End With
        i = i + n - 1
    Next iProc
 
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Font.Size = 9
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Borders.LineStyle = x1None
    For x = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Columns(x).EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next x
       
    
    
 End Sub
```

I am trying to make a code that can eliminate the dependency of moving the sheets from multiple workbooks to destination workbook and copy values along with header names for all the matched and unmatched column headers.

Headers are in row 1 in all the worksheets.
Total rows - 50000+
Total columns - 170+

Comment: What should happen to unmatched columns?  Is your Database sheet empty when you start the process?  Does it already contain headers?   FYI if you post code fome somewhere else (eg. your `UpdateData` method) it's useful to let us know you didn't write it yourself, or we will get the wrong idea about how comfortable you are with VBA and wonder why you're asking the question ;-)

Comment: Database sheet is empty at the beginning. I am looking to add columns from all the different sheets into one. (some column headers exist in other files while some are not) , so I wanted to add all the column headers along with the row data. I am not well versed with vba and took the UpdateData function from community and made modifications according to my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested, and working for me.

EDIT: made a bunch of fixes.

```vb
Sub ProcessWorkbooks()
    
    Dim f, wsData As Worksheet, wbSrc As Workbook, map As Object
    
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    wsData.UsedRange.ClearContents 'clear any existing data
    
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\New folder\Exec_072021.xlsb", Password:="**********")
    ImportData wbSrc, wsData
    wbSrc.Close False
    
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\New folder\Non Exec_072021.xlsb", Password:="**********")
    ImportData wbSrc, wsData
    wbSrc.Close False
    
    With wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Font.Size = 9
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Borders.LineStyle = xlLineStyleNone
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Sub ImportData(wbIn As Workbook, wsData As Worksheet)
    
    Dim lrData As Long, lrSrc As Long, ws As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim Process, hdr, m
    
    
    Process = Array("Manila", "Cebu", "Davao", "CDO", "Bacolod")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ws In wbIn.Worksheets
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Process, 0)) Then 'process this sheet?
            lrData = SheetLastRow(wsData) + 1
            If lrData = 1 Then lrData = 2 'in case no headers yet...
            lrSrc = SheetLastRow(ws)
            For Each c In ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
                hdr = c.Value
                
                m = Application.Match(hdr, wsData.Rows(1), 0) 'existing column match?
                If IsError(m) Then
                    m = Application.CountA(wsData.Rows(1))
                    m = IIf(m = 0, 1, m + 1)
                    wsData.Cells(1, m).Value = hdr 'add as new column header
                End If
                
                ws.Range(c.Offset(1), ws.Cells(lrSrc, c.Column)).Copy _
                        wsData.Cells(lrData, m)
            Next c
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

'return the last used row in a worksheet
Function SheetLastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = ws.Cells.Find("*", ws.Range("A1"), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then SheetLastRow = f.Row 'otherwise 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Pls find the result post testing. 
- Data only coming in column A of database sheet, all other 167 columns coming blank. 
- Column A data is incomplete and giving blanks in between.
- Code is using row 1 of database sheet as headers, ideally the code should create headers from all the different sheets and then copy paste data for those columns headers into database sheet. Also, can we remove the dependency of hardcoding the worksheet names in the code ("Manila", "Cebu", "Davao", "CDO", "Bacolod") and also file path and instead ask user to select the files.?

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Thanks Tim, the program is working now. Few things....1) getting 4-5 blank rows from each worksheets to database while copying data. (Can we just use column A from each sheet to get the last row range ?)...... 2) as mentioned earlier, the sheet names & workbooks in code are hardcoded, can we allow the code to execute for all sheets and any workbook instead (as there can be a new site in future).

Comment: Why don't you try to make those changes?  They should be pretty strtaightforward.

Comment: I was able to remove the fixed filepaths from the code and used the folder picker instead....I will try to look into the issue of getting few blank rows after each copy paste into database sheet....thanks

Comment: If you want to remove the hard-coded sheet names, you only need to remove the test `If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, Process, 0)) Then`.  Switching to ColumnA to find the next row on the Data sheet - `lrData = wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Still getting the total row from each worksheet in the database sheet (which is +2 from last record in each sheet) post making the recommended changes. can you pls review how to get rid of the total row from getting pasted. I can share the data file if req.....thank you for the support.

Comment: How would I know there's a Totals row?  If it's always +2 then try subtracting 2 from `lrSrc`

Comment: Thank you! taking 5-6 mins on 25861 records and getting the desired output.

Comment: Good to hear it's working out.